# How can I exclude certain posts from Wordpress RSS feeds?

Tags: wordpress, post, rss, feed

Is there a way to exclude a post from all of Wordpress' RSS feeds (the default one as well as tags, categories, and search feeds)?

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you do not want to use plugins like [THIS ONE](http://coffee2code.com/wp-plugins/stealth-publish/) or [THIS](http://www.planetmike.com/plugins/ultimate-category-excluder/), you have many ways :

One is to assign a category for the posts you would like to exclude and then you can just change the URL of the RSS link like so :

```
http://www.mydomain.com/feed?cat=-x,-y,-z
```

You can also FILTER with a function :

```
function o99_my_rss_filter($query) {
if ($query->is_feed) {
$query->set('cat','-7'); //Put category ID - here it is : 7
}
return $query;
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts','o99_my_rss_filter');
```

The point is that you will need to assign SOMETHING (tag, custom field, category) to identify what to exclude , assuming that you do not want always to add the ID to exclude from the query.

The easiest is by category as demonstrated above .

**** Edit I **

Just for the sake of it - (I still recommend  the cetegory method) r
Even if I dislike custom-fields when they are overused - this is another way that change the query by assigning a custom field :

```
function o99_my_rss_filter_by _field( $where, $wp_query = NULL ) {
    global $wpdb;

    if ( !$wp_query ) global $wp_query;if ( $wp_query->is_feed ) {

        $posts = get_posts( array( 'meta_key' => 'norss' ) );

        if ( $posts ) {
            foreach( $posts as $post ) {
                $exclude .= $post->ID . ',';
            }
        }
        $exclude = substr( $exclude,0, strlen( $exclude )-1 );

        $where .= ' AND $wpdb->posts.ID NOT IN ( ' . $exclude . ')';
    }
    return $where;
}
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'o99_my_rss_filter_by _field', 1, 4 );
```